# Correct approach to pass data to service layer

Tags: architecture, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, services, asp.net-core

I'm curious what's considered the (best) correct way to pass data to a service layer in ASP.net Core. Say I have a `Person` entity that has a relation to a `Image` (profile picture) entity and another relation to a `Address` entity.

Should the signature of the service method look like this:

`public Person CreateCustomer(Person person, Address address, Image profilePicture)`

Or would it make more sense to put all the needed data in an interface:

`public Person CreateCustomer(ICustomerDetails details)`

Using the last approach, I would be able to make my ViewModel inherent from `ICustomerDetails` and I could pass the ViewModel from the controller directly to the service layer.

What approach would be most advisable in this situation.

Comment: your CreateCustomer method doesnt make much sense. It returns a Person and take a Person as an input

Comment: @Ewan The idea was that the Person entity would contain the person data needed for creating the database record and the method would return the Person created in database.

Comment: @jerojitov this question is impossible to answer because there is no one-size-fits-all correct approach to defining contracts. The contract should be *exactly what you need it to be for you software to work*. No more, no less. Don't over-design your code.

Comment: The best approach is always the one that (in this order): *works* and *meet your needs*. As you may guess, we can not answer these questions for you. If you are fine with both, then apply KISS and YAGNI to make a choice

Comment: "Using the last approach, I would be able to make my ViewModel inherent from ICustomerDetails and I could pass the ViewModel from the controller directly to the service layer." That's no ViewModel; it's a Model.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to:

1. Name your methods for what they do

   `public void Repository.SavePerson(Person person)`
2. When you save a Person object, you only need to send the Person object
3. Ensure your object has all the properties that are associated with it

eg

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Id;
    public string Name;
    public Image ProfileImage;
    public Address ContactAddress;
}
```